# ParameterPValues

Tags: probability-or-statistics, fitting

I am currently translating a Mathematica notebook for model fitting into Python, and I need to understand one property of `NonLinearModelFit`.
Could anyone link to a resource, or better yet explain, what `ParameterPValues` refers to and how they are calculated?
The only explanation I can find is that it comes from the Z-test, but not how it is actually calculated. I am sorry, but I am not very experienced in statistics, hence the problems.

Thank you

Comment: If you store the results from `NonlinearModelFit` in `nlm`, then `nlm["ANOVATable"]` will get you the degrees of freedom associated with the error term and `nlm["ParameterTable"]` will get you the t-Statistics and P-values.  That will be enough information to determine how the P-values are calculated.